# Async function in another window

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, .net-framework-version

I'm having issues with running a function as async.  I'm trying to make an async call to set up some timmers to run some code. I've tried making the function async and I feel like I'm doing something wrong.  I've narrowed down the functionality to two functions and added a  20-second sleep in the function to test out the issue and I'm wondering if my sleep is pausing the whole application or am I doing async incorrectly?  Any point in the right direction would be helpful.  Thank you in advance.

```
private async void RunAsyncExample(){
    Task timersTask = mainWindow.StartTimers();   //This has a 20 sec sleep
    mainWindow.PullReceipt(handoff);              //This should not wait
    await timersTask;                             //This should wait
}
```

Below is the mainWindow.StartTimers

```
public async Task<Task> StartTimers()
{
    _log.LogError("starting timer");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
    _log.LogError("ending timer");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public async Task StartTimers()
{
    _log.LogError("starting timer");
    await Task.Delay(20000);
    _log.LogError("ending timer");
}
```

Incidentally, your code has many issues:

- You should not declare an `async` method if it doesn't `await`
- You should not `Sleep`
- You should put non UI code outside UI
- You should name methods properly. `StartTimers` doesn't start any timer, so it is not an appropriate name.
- `async void` is appropriate only for asynchronous event handlers